# MySQL error when create message_id in my table

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I have a table `message`. And I tried to create table `contests` with `message_id` foreign key.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `message` (
  `chat_id` bigint COMMENT 'Unique chat identifier',
  `id` bigint UNSIGNED COMMENT 'Unique message identifier',

  ....

  PRIMARY KEY (`chat_id`, `id`),

  ...

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

And my table `contests`

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contests` (
  `id` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID записи',
  ...

  `message_id` bigint UNSIGNED COMMENT 'ID сообщения с кнопкой',
  `chat_id` bigint COMMENT 'Так надо',

  ...

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

  FOREIGN KEY (`message_id`) REFERENCES `message` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`chat_id`) REFERENCES `message` (`chat_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

> Error:  Create table 'admin_bot/contests' with foreign key constraint
>   failed. There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced
>   columns appear as the first columns.

Comment: Make the id field in messages table first field. No need to make chart_I'd a pk. You can simply add unique index on this field.

Comment: is your message or user table referenced correct primary key? - luis

Comment: @wafutech sorry, i can't understand how it make :(

Comment: Can you remove `chat_id` from `PRIMARY KEY ('chat_id', 'id'),`?

Comment: @clinomaniac no, it's a system and important table. And there are many records in the table, I'm afraid to edit something

Comment: Do you have `chat_id` in the `contests` table?

Comment: @clinomaniac no, that's not need

Comment: Your issue is that the foreign key from the `contests` table doesn't match the primary key of the `message` table. You either need to use just the `id` as a key in the `message` table or add `chat_id` in the `contests` table.

Comment: @clinomaniac oh... okay, thank you a lot!

Comment: @clinomaniac I tried to add a `chat_id` column, but I've got an error again. Updated my question...

Comment: Try to create one key like the primary key of the first table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the primary key of a table to reference it in a foreign key of a table. Your SQL needs to look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contests` (
  `id` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID записи',
  ...

  `message_id` bigint UNSIGNED COMMENT 'ID сообщения с кнопкой',
  `chat_id` bigint COMMENT 'Так надо',

  ...

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

   FOREIGN KEY (`chat_id`, `message_id`) REFERENCES `message` (`chat_id`, `id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```